# Guzzle/Curl weird error when sending twice

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm having problem sending on the second request. I tried to use Curl but the problem still persist.

I have a class that use guzzle to call to an existing api it look like this.

```php
class HttpCall
{
    public static function request($method, $endpoint, $payload)
    {
      $client = new Client();

      $response = $client->request(...);

      return $response;
    }
}
```

Then I have a service class that use the HttpCall to fetch some data on another server

The flow is like this

```
 Search Name (Request to another endpoint) > Update Data (Request to another endpoint)
```

so this two flow search name and update data each request a token to the server

```
Authenticate (Request to login and get token) > Search Name
Authenticate (Request to login and get token) > Update data
```

My service class is like this

```php
class MyService
{
    public function searchName($name)
    {
      $request = HttpCall::request(...);

      return $request;
    }


    public function updateData($payload)
    {
     $request = HttpCall::request(...);

     return $request;
    }
}
```

then in my Class that actually interact with the events

```
class MyClass
{
   public function __construct(MyService $service)
   {
     $this->service = $service;
   }

   public function update()
   {
      // When I remove this, It's working and hardcoded some data
      $data = $this->service->searchName('test'); 

      $updateData = [...];

      $this->service->updateData($updateData);

   }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's happening why the request seem's to fail (sometimes)

Thanks for help guys